# How to avoid / prevent Max Redirects error with requests in Python?

Tags: python, http, web, request, python-requests

Trying to avoid getting a `Number of Redirects Exceeds 30` error with `python-requests`.  Is there something I can do to avoid it, or is it purely server-side?  I got this error while trying to `GET` `facebook.com`.

Thanks very much!

Comment: That is a server-side problem where you continue to be redirected by the server. You'll need to figure out *why* you are being redirected so often.

Comment: You can just catch and handle this error using ```try ... except: ...``` statement.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You should add your comment as a response.  Oleg, thanks for that pointer.  I was more interested in finding out if something was being done the wrong way.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto: Done, plus info on how to start debugging the redirect loop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *server* is redirecting you in a loop. You'll need to figure out why you are being redirected so often.

You could try to see what goes on by *not* allowing redirects (set `allow_redirects=False`), then resolving them using the [`.resolve_redirects()` API](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Session.resolve_redirects):

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/redirect/5'  # redirects 5 times
>>> session = requests.session()
>>> r = session.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
>>> r.headers.get('location')
'/redirect/4'
>>> for redirect in session.resolve_redirects(r, r.request):
...     print redirect.headers.get('location')
... 
/redirect/3
/redirect/2
/redirect/1
/get
None
```

The `redirect` objects are proper responses; print out from these what you need to figure out why you end up in a redirect loop; perhaps the server is providing clues in the headers or the body.

Comment: Wow, this is better than I expected.  Thanks a lot!  I'll try this out soon.  Thanks!

Comment: http://httpbin.org/redirect/5 is every helpful in debugging - thanks for referencing that!